# How to make labels in boxplot vertical in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have too many labels on the x-axis. How can I project them vertically?
I can't find the right arguments...

```
   boxplot(df$y$x, data=df, drop = TRUE, main = "Boxplot y vs x", ylab="y", xlab="x")
```

Hopefully someone can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggplot2` you can do something like this

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
            geom_boxplot(aes(x = x,
                             y = y))+
            ggtitle("Boxplot y vs x") +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get "Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Did you use %>% instead of +?"

Comment: Yes. Sorry, edited the awnser. Replace %>% for a +.